When I start my car it lags like the battery is dying but it’s new and it’s ticking when I put in drive but just got oil changed
2011 Hyundai genesis 4.6 the car was a little low on oil it was driven fast RPMs were high they were in manual. as soon as they stoped it died.. tried to start just clicked. I thought it was seize. They hooked up jumper cables and starter started smoking.. Left it for a few days. Few days later. Had someone go check it out. It started don’t really know what they did. But it lags on start. they said oil isn’t getting to top of motor that it could be and oil pump. When it’s goes in drive and accelerates it ticks…. It’s like a whining tick sound. When it first starts and idle you don’t hear ticking.  Put it in drive and accelerate you hear it. Back to idle you hear it but not too much.. Not sure what to do to fix I know I should drive it. Anyone know what I could do to fix it. Or should I just take it to shop.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
